# use Kallisto in galaxy

Tags: sequence-alignment, transcriptome, galaxy, kallisto

I want to use [Kallisto](https://pachterlab.github.io/kallisto/about) for sequence alignment in Galaxy. Its description is:

> a program for quantifying abundances of transcripts from bulk and
> single-cell RNA-Seq data, or more generally of target sequences using
> high-throughput sequencing reads.

However, I found this field empty:

> **there is no option available for the reference transcriptome.**

- How I use a reference sequence?
- Can I leave the other configuration by default?

- this is the link of the tool:  https://usegalaxy.org/root?tool_id=toolshed.g2.bx.psu.edu/repos/iuc/kallisto_quant/kallisto_quant/0.43.1.3

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to click on the dropdown menu and select "Use transcriptome from history", which will allow you to specify your own file.

[image]

I suspect the default will be built-in human transcriptome.

Solution is not tested, so let us know if it actually works.